# Animate bottom navigation bar with Animated.View

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated-v2

Attempting to hide/show the bottom navigation bar on React-Native app

When wrapping the navigation tab With `<Animated.view>` the navigation styling collapses and the bottom tab bar jumps to the top of the screen and requires much styling to put it back to to place.

Using React-Native-Reanimated is there a way to animate the bottom tab appearance?

**Working example:**

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
...
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
...
<Tab.Navigator tabBarStyle: {
      display: tabBarVisability,> 
      ... 
</Tab.Navigator>
```

**Desired:**

```
<Animated.View>
  <Tab.Navigator>    
  </Tab.Navigator>    
</Animated.View>
```

Comment: you can pass the `tabBar` prop to the tab navigator, which allows you to pass in a custom component. Have you experimented with that at all?

Comment: That's an option, but it means recreating the whole navigation component, seems excessive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Abe, the solution was to add the `tabBar` prop, wrapping the `BottomTabBar` with `Animated.View`

This is a working example:

```
import Animated, { FadeInUp, FadeOutDown, Layout } from 'react-native-reanimated';

import { BottomTabBar, createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

...

<Tab.Navigator
  ...props
  tabBar={(props) => (
    <Animated.View
      entering={FadeInUp}
      exiting={FadeOutDown}
      layout={Layout.duration(100)}
      style={{
        height: tabBarVisible ? 80 : 0,
      }}
    >
      <BottomTabBar {...props} />
    </Animated.View>
  )}
...Screens
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this fading animation in React Native Navigation **v6**?